# How to treat file contents as String

Tags: java, file, text, dictionary

I am creating a Scrabble game that uses a dictionary. For efficiency, instead of loading the entire dictionary (via txt file) to a Data Structure (Set, List etc.) is there any built in java class that can help me treat the contents of the file as String.

Specifically what I want to do is check whether a word made in the game is a valid word of the dictionary by doing something simple like fileName.contains (word) instead of having a huge list that is memory inefficient and using list.contains (word).

Do you guys have any idea on what I may be able to do. If the dictionary file has to be in something other than a txt file (e.g. xml file), I am open to try that as well.

NOTE: I am not looking for http://commons.apache.org/io/api-1.4/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#readFileToString%28java.io.File%29

**This method is not a part of the java API.**

HashSet didn't come to mind, I was stuck in the idea that all contains () methods used O(n) time, thanks to Bozho for clearing that with me, looks like I will be using a HashSet.

Comment: How is a HashSet<String> more inefficient than what you're proposing? I would venture to propose just the opposite -- that searching for the word is much more efficient, possibly enough to be noticeable by the user if the data is large enough.

Comment: "This method is not a part of the java API." ... so what? And whether you read it as a string in memory, or as a collection in memory - it doesn't make a diference

Comment: I think your problem is not dealing with file to string transformation, but with using RandomAccessFile to store and read a dictionary file without loading the whole data on memory (perhaps with a cache level implemented). also if you only need to verify that a word is in a dictionary consider looking into bloom filters.

Comment: So can you include third party libraries at all or are you stuck with just what's in the Java API?

Comment: I am stuck with the API because I don't have enough rights on my dev computer to access external classes

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think your best option is to load them all in memory, in a `HashSet`. There `contains(word)` is O(1).

If you are fine with having it in memory, having it as `String` on which to call `contains(..)` is much less efficient than a `HashSet`.

And I have to mention another option - there's a data structure to represent dictionaries - it's called [`Trie`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie). You can't find an implementation in the JDK though.

A very rough calculation says that with all English words (1 million) you will need ~12 megabytes of RAM. which is a few times less than the default memory settings of the JVM. (1 million * 6 letters on average * 2 bytes per letter = 12 milion bytes, which is ~12 megabytes). (Well, perhaps a bit more to store hashes)

If you really insist on not reading it in memory, and you want to scan the file for a given word, so you can use a [`java.util.Scanner`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) and its `scanner.findWithHorizon(..)`. But that would be inefficient - I assume O(n), and I/O overhead.

Comment: My thoughts exactly, +1. Or if the data is too large to hold all in memory, then of course the solution would be to use a database.

Comment: @Bozho: Java uses 2 bytes per character, not 1, so your estimate of 6MB of RAM should be 12MB.

Comment: The RAM usage math is wrong. Way wrong. It doesn't include string object overhead (which at even 4 bytes per object [but it is much more] is...) or take into account of the internal string encoding. However, nice simple answer otherwise +1.

Comment: @Ciaran McHale that was my initial calculation. But for ASCII _I think_ it uses 1 byte.

Comment: FWIW: There are some UTF-8 String implementation as [here](http://javadoc.iaik.tugraz.at/iaik_jce/current/iaik/asn1/UTF8String.html) and [here](http://www.mozilla.org/projects/security/pki/jss/javadoc/org/mozilla/jss/asn1/UTF8String.html)

Comment: ASCII is 16 bit meaning 2 bytes. Furthermore, when playing with Strings, the memory usage shoots up because a new object is created for each string, just imagine.

Comment: it will still be much less than the default limit. And ASCII is not 16 bit. It's 7 bit.

Comment: @Bozho The issue is that a String in Java (at least on the normal JVM) is stored in a `char[]` internally using a UTF-16 encoding (there can be surrogate pairs). So every ASCII letter requires one `char` or two bytes (in the JVM).

Comment: yes, I know. I somehow assumed the lower ranges can be represented with fewer bits, but this isn't the case.

Answer (score 3):

While a HashSet is likely a perfectly acceptable solution (see Bozho's answer), there are other data-structures that can be used including a Trie or Heap.

The advantage a [Trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) has is that, *depending upon implementation details*, the starting prefix letters can be shared (a trie is also called a "prefix tree", after all). Depending upon implementation structure and data, this may or may not actually be an improvement.

Another option, especially if file-based access is desired, is to use a [Heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_%28data_structure%29) -- Java's PriorityQueue is actually a heap, but it is not file-based, so this would require finding/making an implementation.

All of these data-structures (and more) can be implemented to be file-based (use more IO *per lookup* -- which could actually be less overall -- but save memory) or implemented directly (e.g. use SQLite and let it do it's B-Tree thing). SQLite excels in that it can be a "common tool" (once used commonly ;-) in a toolbox; data importing, inspection, and modification is easy, and "it just works". SQLite is even used in less powerful systems such as Android.

HashSet comes "for free" with Java, but there is no standard Trie or file-based Heap implementation. I would start with a HashSet - Reasoning:

1. Dictionary = 5MB.
2. Loaded into HashSet (assuming lots of overhead) = 20MB.
3. Memory usage in relation to other things = Minimal (assumes laptop/desktop)
4. Time to implement with HashSet = 2 Minutes.
5. I will have only "lost" 2 Minutes if I decide a HashSet wasn't good enough :-)

Happy coding.

---

Links to random data-structure implementations (may or may not be suitable):

- [TernarySearchTrie](http://jaspell.sourceforge.net/javadocs/pt/tumba/spell/TernarySearchTrie.html) Reads in a flat file (must be specially constructed?)
- [TrieTree](http://lexsrv3.nlm.nih.gov/LexSysGroup/Projects/lvg/2010/docs/apiDoc/gov/nih/nlm/nls/lvg/Trie/TrieTree.html) Has support for creating the Trie file from a flat file. Not sure if this Trie works from disk.
- [FileHash](http://wordfreak.sourceforge.net/api/org/annotation/util/FileHash.html) Hash which uses a file backing.
- [HashStore](http://www.cellspark.com/hashstore.html) Another disk-based hash
- [WB B-Tree](http://people.csail.mit.edu/jaffer/WB) Simple B-tree implementation / "database"
- [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) Small embedded RDBMS.
- [UTF8String](http://www.mozilla.org/projects/security/pki/jss/javadoc/org/mozilla/jss/asn1/UTF8String.html) Can be used to significantly reduce the memory requirements of using `HashSet<String>` when using a Latin dictionary. (String in Java uses UTF-16 encoding which is minimum of two bytes/character.)

Comment: @Bozho It's okay, I started with Trie and stole HashSet from yours ;-) I added the list later when I realized the simple solution was ... just "good enough".

Answer (score 1):

You need to compress your data to avoid having to store all those words. The way to do so would be a tree in which nodes are letters and leaves reflect the end of a word. This way you're not storing repetitive data such as `the there these` where those words all have the same prefix.

There is a way to make this solution even more memory efficient. (Hint: letter order)

Answer (score -1):

Use the readline() of java.io.BufferedReader. That returns a string.

```
String line = new BufferedReader (new FileReader (file) ).readline ();
```

Comment: Sometimes the best answer is not the answer that the OP wants.

Comment: I don't get it. I understood he was wondering how to load the content of a file into a string.

Comment: I wanted to treat the file contents as a String, not load it into a String variable. Having a variable that is over 200K characters long will be crazy, especially applying linear methods on it.